# How can I integrate the reflection of CG object over a photograph?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, shaders, shadows

So I'm trying to learn some basic VFX to do CGI in the future, and I've started by putting 3D objects in an image. So far, I've got the shadow catcher working, but I can't figure out how to make the cube reflect (?) on the table without reflecting the color too. [image: Reflection problem]

As you can see in the picture above, the aside from the shadow, the real object is being reflected into the table, but in a shadowy way (in the red rectangle). Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45516/how-to-get-reflections-from-3d-to-show-up-on-real-images/45632#45632