# how do I add reflections to the ground in tracking?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, tracking

I am able to add shadows using the ground but I am unable to figure out how to add a reflection from the object to the ground. I tried to add a material to the ground using a glossy shader and a transparent shader with an add shader but its just invisible when rendering. here is an image[image]
how can i achieve a reflection? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is no easy way to do this (one of the things that drives me crazy about cycles.) I suggest you take a look at this link https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45516/how-to-get-reflections-from-3d-to-show-up-on-real-images/45632#45632                                                           You could always try using RenderMan for Blender, they have a one click option of doing this. Much like the way shadow capture works with Cycles. What you are looking for is a reflection pass.