# Render Reflection in Blender 2.8 Cycles

Tags: rendering

I am having trouble my reflections only with cycles in Blender 2.8.

With the interface change from blender 2.79 to 2.8 the layers concept is a little different, and I don't know how to render an object with its reflection, without rendering the material it is reflecting off of.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. What do layers have to do with reflection? Can you provide a concrete example from 2.79 of something specific you're trying to do? Is it that you want a reflective object whose reflection shows various other objects which don't actually appear in the scene themselves?

Comment: My guess @acro: [How to get reflections from 3D to show up on real images?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45516/how-to-get-reflections-from-3d-to-show-up-on-real-images?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @acro Yes, exactly what p2or said. Sorry if I was unclear. But in the new blender update I can't find this layers option. Is there a better/different way to approach this problem?