# 3D animated glass object in video -> how to add reflection

Tags: reflection

I have a question regarding reflection.

I took a video from me holding a wooden plate and I want to create an aquarium filled with water on it.

I created the aquarium and the water and everything is working perfectly but I have no clue how I make the water and the glass bowl reflect the backround (me). That you can see the reflections of myself and of the wood and so on.

Can you please help me and give me some input how I can do that?

Here is a picture how it looks like so far. As you can see the aquarium is black because there is nothing that is reflecting in it.
For information, I have set the video as a background in my camera settings in blender.

[image: Picture_1]

Thank you very much,
Luelaes

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to find an HDRI that fits the video lighting, and then use that as the world background.

Comment: somehow related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45516/how-to-get-reflections-from-3d-to-show-up-on-real-images/45632#45632

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140477/30849

Answer (score 2):

Tough one, in the reflection you would see the person holding the tank, but from a different perspective (arms. chest and head and the sky behind).

[image]

So to get an accurate reflection, you would need to generate a 3d character that matches the person holding the tank, or shoot some video from a low angle that contains the image that would be reflected and map that onto the surface of the water.

The cheapest (and inaccurate) way to do this would be to create a surface that reflects a plane with the current image mapped to it. That plane would need to be invisible to the camera but visible to glossy rays.

[image]

Comment: Hello, yes that is a very good idea with the model, I will try that out,

Thank you :-)