# How to make material like shadow catcher, but for reflection(not shadow)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Let's we have this setup:

[image]
[image]

Sky is black for camera and textured for reflection:

[image]

And I want to remove sky from reflection on the ground like this:

[image]

And the way that I found is using a post processing nodes like this:

[image]

But there is a few disadvantages for this method:

1. If I add lamps (any emission material) they are also subtracted.
2. Cycles passes are not denoised. So, this method looks bad with build-in denosing.

Any outer way to achieve this task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How can I reflect a transparent background?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27934/how-can-i-reflect-a-transparent-background/45625#45625)

Comment: @cegaton coll solution from top rated post, but doesn't works with textured environment.

Comment: I ended up using that excellent tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cr4828-YfSU

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This is more of a hack.]

Duplicate your Glossy floor plane and assign it an invisible **Refraction BSDF**. Scale it to wards the Camera as little as possible.

[image]

After doing this, all rays bouncing of the Glossy floor plane will pass through the Refraction plane and have the **Is Transmission Ray** set. They will also be at a ray depth of 4 after leaving the transmissive plane. If it hits the world output at this point, we want it to be black. If there are more bounces, it isn't the direct ray from camera-transmission-reflection-transmission-world and shouldn't be black.

With nodes, combine the Ray Depth <= 4, Transmission Ray and Camera Ray parameters.

[image]

The result will also work if other emissive objects are added to the scene.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This hack works great!

Comment: that is genius!