# How do you get lights to interact with a motion track? I can get shadows but I cant get lights to show

Tags: lighting, motion-capture

[image]Im using a mesh with an emission shader hidden in the engines, it will light the uwing itself but wont cast light on the floor that the shadows are cast in
[image: Im using a mesh with an emission shader hidden in the engines, it will light the uwing itselve but wont cast light on the floor that the shadows are cast in[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inBWT.jpg)

Comment: Related, possibly helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107757/how-to-make-material-like-shadow-catcher-but-for-reflectionnot-shadow