# Product shots - Rendering shadows only below the object, not on the whole shadow catcher

Tags: transparency, shadows, shadowcatcher

Is there a way to render the shadow and the reflections only below the object? I'm rendering product shots and I want a shadow below them that isn't on a whole shadow catcher plane below the product. I've tried to edit the falloff of the shadow catcher but I get a lot of noise this way.
Here is the node setup:
[image]

And here is the result:
[image]

It's kinda close to the result I want but it's still not it. It's supposed to look good on a purely white background.

[image]

I've also achieved the effect above but without using the shadow catcher and by brightening the background in Photoshop, the background isn't transparent though. That's how I'd like it to look but with the transparent background.
Can anyone help me with finding a proper way to do it in Blender without making the background transparent in Photoshop? I've been trying to do it for a long time.

Comment: does https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107757/how-to-make-material-like-shadow-catcher-but-for-reflectionnot-shadow help?

Comment: Well, not really.