# How to render ground reflections without rendering the ground?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, lighting, reflection

I'd like to create a product shot like the following images for a client:

[image]

[image]

I'm relatively new to Blender, I don't know that much about render passes.

What I would like to do is render the bottle, with the reflection with a transparent background. I do'nt know if this is possible, if its not, maybe there is another way to get this result. Please keep in mind that I'm new to this program.

Comment: In Cycles you it should work, in Eevee you need to add a Light Probe > Reflection Cubemap, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190642/how-do-i-get-proper-reflections-eevee/190650#190650

Comment: Please prefer using the image tool of this site to provide images. If not your question has no mean when your link is no more available. Thanks

Comment: The reflections on the glass or on the ground? Please describe in *detail* what you'd like to achieve and what you have tried to far. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried to tidy up your question and added the gist of your comment to it, hope that's fine @Touta In the meantime I recommend take the tour to learn how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thanks.

Comment: Does any one know how to do this? I want to render the ground reflection with the product only without rendering the ground... Like a shadowcatcher, but for reflections

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107757/how-to-make-material-like-shadow-catcher-but-for-reflectionnot-shadow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make material like shadow catcher, but for reflection(not shadow)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107757/how-to-make-material-like-shadow-catcher-but-for-reflectionnot-shadow)

Comment: Kind of... but the background and plane isn't transparent? correct me if I'm wrong. @batFINGER

Comment: Probably something from here is also a good option: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+render+reflection

Comment: I know this isn't an exact fit and probably way too complicated for your specific task, but [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdqV4oortP0) should cover pretty much everything for rendering and compositing with glass and real footage. Also you can render glass with alpha by enabling the *Transparent Glass* checkbox in the render settings.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer strictly... but...

[image]

Use a mirror modifier:

[image]

Works for Cycles and Eevee ; )

You can improve it for instance using UV parameters of the modifier.

If you shift its U to 1:

[image]

that can give a clue that you can use in the shader, to obtain this for instance:

[image]

to use it you can make a node group that you can plug into the alpha input of the principled BSDF (node group as you may have several materials).

[image]

The top line uses UV X coordinate (U) to look if under 1 (the mirrored part is over 1 because of the parameter in the modifier).

The bottom line uses Z coordinate to tune a progressive value from 1 to 0 as Z goes down.

Comment: Not the answer that I was looking for... But it works, really really well... Thankyou so much!

Comment: Note that you can use the modifier "data" part to move the UVs and use that in order to have an eventually different shader for it (like adding some transparency to the mirrored part).

Comment: @lemon interesting ... How does it work? I'm stack in UV as coordinates for texture, but how about different shader? Thanks a lot for insight.

Comment: @vklidu, edited for an example.

Comment: Now this is full blown cheating... :) +1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images @JachymMichal