# How to create a reflective shadow catcher wo composition?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

i have tried to create a material to be transparent to catch shadow and to receive reflection from the objects in the scene but not the world, after playing with material nodes for a while i have found that with the ray length node from light path i can extract a map from the object for transparency visibility of the plane but i didn't found how to use it in the plane only if there was a way to translate that data back into the plane material it would be useful .

another thing that i'd been thinking was to find a way to limit the reflectivity distance of the plane if there was a way to limit the plane from receiving reflections .

i really don't want to dive into post processing process , this is kind of challenge to do it within the cycles ...

---

so after a while searching i have found this gold link
[How to make material like shadow catcher, but for reflection(not shadow)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107757/how-to-make-material-like-shadow-catcher-but-for-reflectionnot-shadow)

although it kind of creates what i was searching for but this is not actually the answer to this question because what if the background isn't black ?