# Render light reflection to overlay onto video

Tags: rendering, lighting

I am working on a stopmotion video, and I wanted to ad some Cg elements that we don't have because of budget reasons. Ambient lamps and other lighting objects. I roughly reconstructed the set that we have, and I wanted to render out the reflection of the light on these objects, without rendering the actual Objects, so that I can overlay these in my Video editing software to add the effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45516/how-to-get-reflections-from-3d-to-show-up-on-real-images/45632#45632

Comment: Yes or no questions are not a good fit for this site, as it stands this is too broad. What you ask is possible, but you should focus your question on specific parts you are having trouble with

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27934/how-can-i-reflect-a-transparent-background/45625#45625

Comment: @cegaton Reopened