# Transparency with a Mirror

Tags: objects, transparency, reflection

I made my background transparent to add a different background to it, I got to get the windows to show the transparency background as shown here
[image: Trans1]

But in my mirror, it shows a black background on the windows.
[image: Trans2]

Is there any work around to this?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What are your settings under _Light Paths_ > _Max Bounces_ for _Total_, _Glossy_ and _Transmission_? But I guess, the transparent background doesn't really work with a mirror... because if Blender would render the mirror transparent (since it should be reflecting the transparency of the background) then laying it over a different background wouldn't have a correct reflection of that background in the mirror. Usually the mirror shows the background (if no other object is inbetween) as it is even though it's set to transparent.

Comment: By the way, here are answers on working with mirrors and transparent backgrounds, but that's really not helping if you want a new background to be mirrored correctly in the transparent area: [How can I reflect a transparent background?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27934/)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that too that it'll be a little weird rendering the mirror reflection as a transparent. But what do you think I should do? I set my background transparent, but in the reflections I can't leave it blank dark like that. Any tips?

Comment: No idea how to get correct reflections for a substituted background. But for the black windows in the reflection: but again: a mirror reflects the background though it is transparent, and windows in the reflection should be transparent and show the background through them as well, not be just black. That's why I asked for your _Max Bounces_ settings, but you didn't answer. And I can see in the screenshot that your background is not a simple _Environment Texture_ there's a mix with _Is Glossy Ray_ etc. so this could be a reason, too. But you don't show your _World_ node setup either.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't get to show more info. In this one I use Eeevee, and I tried getting world lighting without its reflections in the glass, https://imgur.com/a/OzY2sSn my glass nodes are mixed with a transparent node. And this is my world sky nodes. https://imgur.com/FKgwssR